# cURL PHP insert POST data to CRM

Tags: php, api, curl

I want to insert data using cURL PHP to my CRM.

If you have another proposition, you can kindly propose it to me

This is my code.

```
<?php
$headers = array(
  "authtoken: REDACTED",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Host: b.maxmind.ma",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
    "Cookie: csrf_cookie_name=bd0baeef023c3e46e1732c3805b9ebc0; sp_session=9c739cc4b357e1cc590b80d511e463492c9faf24",
    "Connection: keep-alive"
);

$curl = curl_init();
$url = "https://b.maxmind.ma/api/leads";

$data = array("name" => "My", "status" => 2, "source" => 3);

$data_string = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
print_r($resp);
?>
```

It shows me **error code: 1020**

Comment: Please don't post auth tokens here. As others can use this service using your auth token.

Comment: I change it. thank you